# How to skip rows based on Group size value of previous row in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm not able to skip next row number 2 (if Group size is 2 in row 1)

```
S.No    title_rcd   passenger_type_rcd  YoungestGroupMember GroupSize   
1   MRS ADULT   ADULT   2   Same Group
2   MR  ADULT   ADULT   2   
3   MR  CHILD   CHILD   1   Unique
4   MR  ADULT   ADULT   1   Unique
5   MR  ADULT   ADULT   2   Same Group
6   MR  INF INF 2
```

Code:

```
for(int r=2;r<=NumberofRows;r++){

    String  getGroupSize=xlsx.getCellData(SheetName, "GroupSize", r);
    float GroupSize=Float.parseFloat(getGroupSize);
    int ActualGroupSize=(int) GroupSize;
    System.out.println("Number of Pax in Row number "+r+" is "+ActualGroupSize);
    ActualGroupSize=nextrow;
```

Expected

> ```
> Number of Pax in Row number 1 is 2
> Number of Pax in Row number 3 is 1
> Number of Pax in Row number 4 is 1
> Number of Pax in Row number 5 is 2
> ```

How to skip row number 2 and 6. Currently with above code am getting values from all the rows.

Comment: This is the table in Excel sheet :

S.No title_rcd passenger_type_rcd YoungestGroupMember GroupSize 
1 MRS ADULT ADULT 2 Same Group
2 MR ADULT ADULT 2 
3 MR CHILD CHILD 1 Unique
4 MR ADULT ADULT 1 Unique
5 MR ADULT ADULT 2 Same Group
6 MR INF INF 2

Comment: _Group size value of previous row_ means what ? Do you want to skip if there is no value in group size ?

Comment: group size is fix or it can be 2, 4,5 any number ?

Comment: Once Group size is 2 in 1st Row, 2nd Row should be skipped.

Comment: And what `Same Group` and `unique` is ?

Comment: Can you share the html for that table? Basically, you have to use `not(preceding::xxx)`. I can provide the xpath if you can share the html for the table.

Comment: In Excel i have a table in the above mentioned format. In 1st Row if Group size is 2, i need to skip 2nd row and get the value of Group size from 3rd Row...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work:

```
        int lastgroupsize = 0;
    for(int r=2;r<=NumberofRows;r++){

        String  getGroupSize=xlsx.getCellData(SheetName, "GroupSize", r);
        float GroupSize=Float.parseFloat(getGroupSize);
        int ActualGroupSize=(int) GroupSize;
        if(lastgroupsize < 2 || (lastgroupsize >= 2 && ActualGroupSize < 2)) {
            System.out.println("Number of Pax in Row number "+r+" is "+ActualGroupSize);
        }
        lastgroupsize = ActualGroupSize;
        ActualGroupSize=nextrow;
```

Comment: last group size can be any value like 5 4 2 3.

Comment: And? I'm not sure if i fully understand the requirement. The code above should remove the lines 2 and 6 from the output. if the previous groupsize is >= 2 and the current group size < 1 it should be printed...